# LINQ pivot on a single field

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have three tables: User, UserRoles and Roles. UserRoles contains the association of the user to one or more roles.

I'm trying to write a LINQ query, using Entity Framework 6, that will produce the output of one user per row listing all the roles associated to the user, like the following:

```
USER      ROLES
John      Administrator, Supervisor
Chiara    Supervisor
Mark      Supervisor, Contributor
```

Currently, my query is the following, but obviously I get duplicated records depending by the number of roles associated with the user:

```
var users = (from u in db.Users.AsNoTracking()
             join ur in db.UserRoles.AsNoTracking() on u.UserId equals ur.UserId into urj
             from urc in urj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             group u by new
             {
                 u.UserId,
                 u.UserName,
                 urc.RoleName,
                 urc.RoleId
             } into grp
             orderby grp.Key.UserName
             select new
             {
                 grp.Key.UserId,
                 grp.Key.UserName,
                 RoleName = grp.Key.RoleName,
                 RoleId = grp.Key.RoleId
             });
```

Is there a way to write one single query, or two at most, or I need to split it? I'm trying to find the best performance and minimize the number of queries done to the database.

Comment: Try : RoleName = string.Join(",", grp.Select(x => x.RoleName).ToArray()),

Comment: @jdweng I'm using LInqToEntities (EF6): LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method.....

Comment: Where does the `Roles` table come into play and why don't you use navigation properties instead of joining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a many-to-many relation between Users and Roles, and you want all (or some) Users, each with all their roles (or some of their roles).

### Use the virtual ICollections!

Apparently you are using Entity Framework. If you have followed the conventions, you will have classes similar to the following:

```
class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    ...

    // every User has zero or more roles (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles {get; set;}
}

class Role
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Role is played by zero or more Users (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

It might be that you have different property names, but the most important part is the `virtual ICollection<...>`. This informs entity framework about the many-to-many relation between Users and Roles.

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the table (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

Entity framework knows the relation between the tables. If you use the collections, entity  framework will automatically translate this in the proper (group-)joins.

**Requirement** Give me (some properties of) all Users, each with their Roles

```
var usersWithTheirRoles = dbContext.Users

    // only if you don't want all Users:
    .Where(user => user.City == "New York")

    .Select(user => new
    {
         // Select only the User properties that you plan to use:
         Id = user.Id,
         Name = user.Name,
         ...

         Roles = user.Roles
             // only if you don't want all Roles
             .Where(role => ...)
             .Select(role => new
             {
                 Id = role.Id,
                 Name = role.Name,
                 ...
             })
             .ToList(),
    });
```

### Do the GroupJoin yourself

If you don't want to use the virtual ICollections, or your entity framework versions doesn't support this, consider to do the groupjoin yourself:

```
var result = dbContext.Users.GroupJoin(dbContext.UserRoles,

user => user.Id,                 // from every User take the Id
userRole => userRole.UserId,     // from every UserRole take the foreign key to User

// parameter resultSelector: for every user, and its zero or more userRoles,
// make one new object, containing the following properties:
(user, userRolesOfThisUser) => new
{
    Id = user.Id,
    Name = usr.Name,

    // for the Roles of this User: groupjoin all Roles with the UserRoles of this User
    Roles = dbContext.Roles.GroupJoin(userRolesOfThisUser,

        role => role.Id               // from every Role take the Id,
        userRole => userRole.RoleId,  // from every UserRole of this user take the foreign key

        // result selector: take every Role, and its zero or more UserRoles
        // that are also UserRoles of this User, to make one new Role:
        (role, userRolesOfThisRole) => new
        {
            Id = role.Id,
            Name = role.Name,
        })
        .ToList(),
});
```

In my opinion the `virtual ICollection` method looks way more elegant and natural.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with single query, you will need to use sub queries or CTE ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv?rq=1)). I would rather create a view with subquery that would return the desired data:

```
Create View ViewUserRoles
AS
SELECT 
    users.UserName AS [User]
    , ROLES = (Select RoleName + ',' From UserRoles Inner Join Roles On UserRoles.RoleId=Roles.RoleId Where UserId=users.UserId FOR XML PATH(''))
    FROM Users users
    Inner Join UserRoles userroles On users.UserId = userroles.UserId
    Group By users.UserName, users.UserId
GO
```